# MVC routing via Global.asax.cs not hitting model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to route to my controller, I cant figure out what i'm doing wrong, and its irritating me.

### Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Groups/{0}/{1}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "GroupSections",
                action = "Details",
                groupName = "",
                sectionName = ""
            }
        );
```

### Controller

```
  public ActionResult Details(string groupName, string sectionName)
    {
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Did you move RegisterRoutes from the RouteConfig class to Global.asax? why? anyhow, perhaps you should move it back to its own class and make sure the method is static void.

Comment: what url are you trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` should not be in your asax, it should be in your `RouteConfig` static class.

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //your route config.
    }
}
```

Edit: Also, as noted in `Brian Mains` answer, your route should resemble:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Where the names in brackets map to the values in the defaults object.

Comment: yeah, cheers for that. I didnt realise it was different in MVC 5 as a pose to 4

Answer (score 2):

If you see [this route examples](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs), your route should be:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Groups/{groupName}/{sectionName}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "GroupSections",
            action = "Details",
            groupName = "",
            sectionName = ""
        }
```

Comment: ah wait, thats not hit my controller

Comment: OK, can you post the signature of the action method that needs to run?

Comment: updated question, with a breakpoint on the controller it still isnt hitting it